# PostgreSQL matrix transformations

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL table called `test` which has 2 columns - (1) `id` & (2) `matrix` as follows: -

```
create table test (id integer, 
                   matrix double precision[]);

insert into test (id, matrix) values
    (1, '{ 0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4}'),
    (2, '{-0.1, -0.2, -0.3, -0.4}'),
    (3, '{ 0.2, -0.2,  0.4, -0.4}'),
    (4, '{-0.5,  0.6, -0.7,  0.8}');
```

The `matrix` column is *always* 4 in size and numbers ranging from `-1` to `1`.

I want to transform `matrix` into an array of size `8` - lets call it `matrix_2`.  If we assume array indexes start at `1` (PostgreSQL style) then: -

- `matrix_2[1]` is the absolute *(positive)* value of `matrix[1]` (but only if `matrix[1] < 0`) *and*
- `matrix_2[2]` is the value of `matrix[1]` (but only if `matrix[1] > 0`).
- *(`matrix_2[3]` and `matrix_2[4]` follow the same pattern for values of `matrix[2]` and so on ...)*
- Values of `0` in the `matrix` array become values of `0` in the 2 entries in the `matrix_2` array.

SQL wise, this is as far as I have got: -

```
select 
    id, 
    matrix,   -- in purely for comparing numbers
    (
        case when matrix[1] < 0::double precision then @matrix[1] else 0::double precision end,
        case when matrix[1] > 0::double precision then matrix[1] else 0::double precision end,    
        case when matrix[2] < 0::double precision then @matrix[2] else 0::double precision end,
        case when matrix[2] > 0::double precision then matrix[2] else 0::double precision end,
        case when matrix[3] < 0::double precision then @matrix[3] else 0::double precision end,
        case when matrix[3] > 0::double precision then matrix[3] else 0::double precision end,
        case when matrix[4] < 0::double precision then @matrix[4] else 0::double precision end,
        case when matrix[4] > 0::double precision then matrix[4] else 0::double precision end
    ) as matrix_2
from 
    test;
```

The returns the following: -

```
---------+-----------------------+--------------------------
id       | matrix                |  matrix_2
interger | double precision []   |  record
---------+-----------------------+--------------------------
1        | {0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4}     | (0,0.1,0,0.2,0,0.3,0,0.4)
2        | {-0.1,-0.2,-0.3,-0.4} | (0.1,0,0.2,0,0.3,0,0.4,0)
3        | {0.2,-0.2,0.4,-0.4}   | (0,0.2,0.2,0,0,0.4,0.4,0)
4        | {-0.5,0.6,-0.7,0.8}   | (0.5,0,0,0.6,0.7,0,0,0.8)
---------+-----------------------+--------------------------
```

The query returns the correct values in the correct order but: -

1. `matrix_2` is of type `record` - not an array of `double precision []`
2. SQL query is pretty horrible i.e. lots of repetition - could defo be more DRY.

Does anyone have any advice on the aforementioned 2 points?

Comment: Just small question - there is R lang for Postgresql - PL/R and it allows all these operations in very easy way. Maybe you could try this? SQL or PL/pgSQL is not the best choice for these things....

Comment: I may go down this route eventually but it's basically to create a database view which I can apply further aggregations on, filtering, sorting etc.

Comment: PL/R allows you to use pg tables of course. No problem here. Beauty of PostgreSQL is you can have one set of tables and work with them with procedures written in different languages. I for example combine PL/pgSQL and Javascript for PostgreSQL PL/V8 in one database - because I work heavily with JSON data and PL/pgSQL is also quite poor in working with JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something linke below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM test,
LATERAL (
    SELECT array_agg( val ) As matrix_2
    FROM (
        SELECT xxx, 1 as ord, 
               case when  matrix[ xxx ] < 0 then abs(matrix[ xxx ]) else 0 end as val
        FROM generate_subscripts( matrix, 1) xxx
        UNION ALL
        SELECT xxx, 2 as ord, 
               case when  matrix[ xxx ] > 0 then abs(matrix[ xxx ]) else 0 end as val
        FROM generate_subscripts( matrix, 1) xxx
        ORDER BY xxx, ord
    ) q
) x;
```

Comment: Works beautifully - nice one!